# xamarin android c# live wallpaper set image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bitmapfactory

I am trying to set multiple images as live wallpaer in Xamarin android app in c# as i am new to bitmapfactory I get error in getResources() java code to c#. Can some one help me out.

```
       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(@"D:\New folder\Downloads\Compressed\Properties\Resources\drawable-hdpi\P.jpg");
           // Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(null, Resource.Drawable.P);
            c.DrawBitmap(bm, 100, 200, null);
```

plz find the solution link:[Solution of multiple images Live Wallpaper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C7SA2bzkUlSVl-1tFLlNjH-kIfM2xQ_J/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i think so answer is in this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9158/getresources-will-not-resolve

Comment: You are trying to use a Windows path